# I want to Modify context account invoice

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I want to Modify context account invoice exactly , i do not want the field in a picture to be filled, i want remove context analytic account and analytic tags
[image]
Thank you

Comment: Hello,
I am not understand your problem can you explain exactly what you want because there is a lot of field that are filled by you

Comment: i want just to avoid 2 field analytic account and analytic tag

Comment: Hello, you what to hiding fields analytic account and analytic tag.

Comment: Why did you activate (Accounting/Settings) "Analytic accounting"? If you don't want to use this feature, deactivate it, and the fields should be gone.

Answer (score 3):

You can inherit this table into your module in xml

```
 <record id="accountinginvisible name " model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">account.inginvisible</field>
                <field name="model">account.invoice.line</field>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="accounting(module name).reference from tree or form view id"/>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <xpath expr="//field[@name='field name']" position="replace" invisible="1">               </xpath>
                </field>
  </record>
```

and in your .py

```
classname(models.Model):
_inherit = 'account.invoice.line'
```

and you can try this and I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to avoid auto fill of `Account` field. It is achieved by calling a `default` function like `_default_account` in field definition.

**Original code:**

```
 account_id = fields.Many2one('account.account', string='Account',
    required=True, domain=[('deprecated', '=', False)],
    default=_default_account,
    help="The income or expense account related to the selected product.")
```

To avoid it, inherit `account.invoice.line` model and redefine that field again without default function.

Try this:

```
_inherit = 'account.invoice.line'

account_id = fields.Many2one('account.account', string='Account',
    required=True, domain=[('deprecated', '=', False)],
    help="The income or expense account related to the selected product.")
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i want just to avoid 2 field analytic account and analytic tag